# Самый простой способ поменять местами строковые элементы массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеем массив:

```
var mass = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4" "elem5"];
```

Какой самый простой способ поменять местами 2 и 4 (к примеру элемент)?
Кроме переприсваивания через дополнительную переменную типа

```
temp1 = mass[2];
mass[2] = mass[4];
mass[4] = temp1;
```

Может быть в Js есть более элегантный способ? (ну как функция .SORT для сортировки)
Или это единственный способ?

Answer (score 18):

В современном js такой способ есть, называется деструктуризирующее присваивание (destructuring assignment):

```
[mass[1], mass[3]] = [mass[3], mass[1]];
```

То есть

```
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Вот только IE11 и Андроиды [так не умеют из коробки](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_assignment), если хочется писать так чтобы работало везде - придется транспилировать.

Еще есть везде-рабочий "ниндзя" способ,  за который в приличном обществе бьют ногами за нечитаемость:

```
mass[1] = [mass[3], mass[3] = mass[1]][0];
```

То есть:

```
a = [b, b = a][0];
```

Comment: Отлично объяснили. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

вот ещё одна старая рабочая "нидзя" для коррекции массива

```
var arr = [2,1,3,5,4,0]
   arr[1] = arr.splice(0,1, arr[1])[0]
//console.log(arr)
```

массивы можно корректировать через метод, для понимания снабдив код комментариями.

```
function correctArr(_arr, _param){  
/*
    коррекция  элементов массива по паре индекса
    *    _arr -- массив требующий коррекции 
    *   _param -- пара [n1,n2] -- индексы массива для взаимной  перестановки
*/
    _arr[_param[1]] = _arr.splice(_param[0],1, _arr[_param[1]])[0]
}
//correctArr(arr, [1,0])
//console.log(arr.toString())
```

можно написать метод c циклом с обращением к функции, и возвращением нового массива

```
function corrects_Arr(){ 
    var _param, _arr = arguments[0].slice(), _arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)  
    for(var i = 0; i < _arguments.length; i++){ 
        correctArr(_arr, _arguments[i])
    }
    return _arr
}
/*
console.log(
    arr.toString() +"  "+ "инспектируемый массив остался прежним"
    +"\n"+
    corrects_Arr(arr, [0,1], [4,3]).toString() +"  "+ "вернули скорректированный массив"
    )
*/
```

для простоты будущего обращения с массивами, можно утяжелить решение задачи, по пути присвоения прототипу конструктора Array своего метода,  который можно будит вызывать на всех массивах.

```
Array.prototype["myCorrects"] = function(_param){ 
    if(_param){
        this[_param[1]] = this.splice(_param[0],1, this[_param[1]])[0]
        this.constructor.prototype.myCorrects.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
    }
    return this
}

arr = arr.myCorrects([0,1], [3,4]).splice(-1,1).concat(arr)
console.log(arr.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Меняем местами второй и третий элемент:

```
var arr = [1,3,2,4,5];
arr.splice(1, 2, arr[2], arr[1]);
//console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Очень хороший способ, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Функция меняет местами два элемента в массиве.

```
export const swap = (arr = [], start = 0, end = 0) => {
  let result = new Map();
  arr.map((_, index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case start:
        return result.set(index, arr[end]);
      case end:
        return result.set(index, arr[start]);
      default:
        return result.set(index, arr[index]);
    }
  });
  return Array.from(result.values());
};
```

[image: Edit swap-two-item-of-array]

Comment: и чем это лучше перекладывания значения через переменную?

Answer (score -3):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
for (var res = [], j  = arr.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 4)
   res.unshift (arr [j - 2]), res.unshift (arr [j - 3]),
   res.unshift (arr [j]),     res.unshift (arr [j - 1]); 
alert (res);
```

Comment: Давайте в цикле подвигаем весь массив, чтобы поменять местами две переменных. П - перформанс.

Comment: Как создание нового массива отвечает на поставленный вопрос?