# Перемещение элементов массива, по зависимому массиву?

Tags: javascript, математика

```
// Есть массив
var a = ["1","2","3","4"];

// Есть массив индексов, по которому он сортируется и выводится:
var b = [1,0,3,2];

var newArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    newArr.push(a[b[i]]);
}

// Получается
newArr == ["2","1","4","3"]


// Я хочу передвинуть в новом массиве newArr значения "3" на первое место.

// Получился такой массив.
["3","2","1","4"]


// Вопрос, как поменять массив a, не трогая массив b, чтобы получился такой массив
["3","2","1","4"] ?
```

---

Добавлю еще один пример:

```
Есть множество значений (массив)
A = ["Имя","Фамилия","Отчество","Должность"];

Есть множество позиций перемещения этих значений
B = [1,0,3,2]

Есть множество D, которое создаётся из значений множества A, размещенных в позиции из множества B
D = ["Фамилия","Имя","Должность","Отчество"] 

("Фамилия" индекс 1 , "Имя" индекс 0, "Должность" индекс 3 , "Отчество" индекс 2) - соответствие множеству B


Но нужно отсортировать множество D вот так
["Имя","Отчество","Фамилия","Должность"]

Но имея возможность изменять лишь множество A, а не B. Множество B константно. Множество D создаётся из и A и B.
```

Comment: Вам нужно что бы  newArr и a имели одинаковые значения?

Comment: вы где менять собрались массив a до того как он зафоритьс или после,

Comment: Нет, массив a не должен быть равен массиву newArr. 
Нужно поменять местами элементы в массиве a, так чтобы затем переместив эти элементы, после цикла for массив newArr принял значение ["3","2","1","4"].

Comment: Нужно понять какой это алгоритм и какой раздел математики решает эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

рекомендую пересмотреть подход к решению вашей задачи в пользу ассоциативных массивов с именованными ключами

вместо гаданий что где и как идёт под номером N, в вашем примере

("Фамилия" индекс N , "Имя" индекс N, "Должность" индекс N , "Отчество" индекс n,...)

используйте конструкцию где каждый ключь соответствует определённому значению

```
var obj = {
  "imay": "Петя",
  "familiya": "Петров",
  "doljnost": "Босс",
  "otchestvo": "Батьковичь"
// и т.д.
}
```

в таком подходе не имеет значения в какой последовательности идут вхождения свойств.

доставать данные, в каком либо нужном порядке можно на прямую обращаясь к объекту

```
var result = obj.imay + " " + obj.otchestvo + " " + obj.doljnost + " " + obj.familiya
```

через вызов функции c передачей в её объекта в качестве аргумента

```
function fu_00a1(_obj){
    return _obj.imay + " " + _obj.otchestvo + " " + _obj.doljnost + " " + _obj.familiya
}

// alert(fu_00a1(obj))

function fu_00a2(_obj){
    return _obj.familiya+ " " + _obj.doljnost + " " + _obj.otchestvo + " " + _obj.imay 
}

// alert(fu_00a2(obj))
```

при создании именованного объекта, в его значения можете передать значения из нумерованного массива Array.

```
var A = ["Имя","Фамилия","Отчество","Должность"];

var obj = {
      "imay": A[0],
      "familiya": A[1],
      "doljnost": A[3],
      "otchestvo": A[2]
    // и т.д.
    }
```

После чего через функции или при помощи прямого обращения создавайте новые массива Array

```
    function fu_00a3(_obj){
        return [_obj.imay, _obj.otchestvo,_obj.doljnost, _obj.familiya]
    }
// alert(fu_00a3(obj))
```

**__ для разнообразия__**

вот ссылкачка на паблик где привожу пример создания метода корректирующего положения элементов в нумерованном массиве

[как на яваскрипт поменять местами элементы массива Array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615117/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/758090#758090)

**Само решение вашей математики**

```
// исходный массив
var A = ["Возраст","Фамилия", "Должность", "Отчество", "Пол", "Имя"];
// массив условия
var condArr = [5,1,3,2]
// новый массив
var newArr = []
for(var i = 0; i < condArr.length; i++){
   newArr[i] = A[condArr[i]]
}
```

P.S. думаю это больше раздел информатики чем математики ))